# MySQL query return all groups where value is part of the group

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table `contract_items`. My `contract_items` table has the fields `item_id` and `contract_id` .

I need to build a query that gets all items from the table with the same `contract_id` as a given item, returning their `item_id`s together in a `group_concat`. The query would have something like a `where in` clause, but in reverse, since I need the entire group based on a single id.

Some thing like:

```
...
where item_id in item_ids
```

How would I do that? The only thing I can think of is subquerying, but that might not scale well.

What I have accomplished so far:

```
select group_concat(i.item_id SEPARATOR ', ')
from contract_items i
where i.contract_id = (
    select contract_id
    from contract_items
    where item_id = itemnum
)
```

How can I make that query better (assuming `itemnum` is the given item)?

Comment: `where i.item_id = itemnum` ?

Comment: Please show your table structure

Comment: try add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `having` clause:

```
select i.contract_id, group_concat(i.item_id SEPARATOR ', ')
from contract_items i
group by i.contract_id
having sum( i.item_id = @itemnum ) > 0;
```

For performance, you might find a subquery better:

```
select i.contract_id, group_concat(i.item_id SEPARATOR ', ')
from contract_items i
where exists (select 1
              from contract_items i2
              where i2.contract_id = i.contract_id and
                    i2.item_id = @itemnum 
             )
group by i.contract_id;
```

This filters before the aggregation (the performance gain) and can use an index on `contract_items(contract_id, item_id)`.